# How to add id and remove added id from anywhere on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a click add and click remove id function using jQuery.

My add function is working fine but I want also when user click anywhere without `.click` button then added id should be remove from `.add` div class.

I have created [this demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mWvgMW) from codepen.io. How can I do that? Or do you have any other method to do that?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="click" data-id="1">Click HERE</div>

   <div class="add">Check</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".click", function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr("data-id");
      $(".add").attr('id', ID);
      // When you click anywhere i want to remove added
      // $(".add").attr('id', ID);
      // Like this $(".add").attr('id', '');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, when you click outside of the green box it will remove id from .add class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".click", function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr("data-id");
      $(".add").attr('id', ID);
      // When you click anywhere i want to remove added
      // $(".add").attr('id', ID);
      // Like this $(".add").attr('id', '');
   });
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".container");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $(".add").attr('id', '');
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:300px;
   margin:0px auto;
   padding:25px;
   background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="click" data-id="1">Click HERE</div>
   
   <div class="add">Check</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `$('.add').removeAttr('id')` to remove id attribute.

Comment: yeah @PavelKozlov, but question is mainly about finding outside click

Comment: @GaneshPutta thanks for your answer. It looks like my answer.